# String Split in C# in this Particular Manner

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

Guys I am Fetching Data From Following Query

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select concat(c1.countryname,' vs ',c2.countryname) as CountryACountryB,r.Description as Round,m.result,m.matchId from matches m left join countries c1 on m.countryId1=c1.countryId left join countries c2 on m.countryId2=c2.countryId left join rounds r on m.roundId=r.roundId where matchId=" + msMatch.SelectedItem.Value, register);
```

When i check i Value coming in CountryACountryB its Argentina Vs Bosnia and Herzegovina(For Eg:)

This is the code i implemented for splitting the String

```
string fullTeam = dr["CountryACountryB"].ToString();
            string[] names = fullTeam.Split(' ', '-');
            string name = names.First();
            string lasName = names.Last();
            string Final = name + ". " + lasName;
```

It does the Job but when it comes to Argentina vs Bosnia and Herzegovina

```
string name = names.First();//Comes as Argentina(Which is Fine)
string lasName = names.Last();//Comes Herzegovina
```

This is the way i want it

```
string Final = name + ". " + lasName;//Argentina + ". " + Bosnia and Herzegovina
```

Any help guys ??

Comment: Just by the way, that seems like it's suspectible to a SQL Injection attack since you're concatenating `msMatch.SelectedItem.Value` instead of parameterizing `matchId`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: is it always `"CountryA vs CountryB"` ?

Comment: Well, you could use a regex and look for " vs. ", but wouldn't it be easier to just return the two country names separately in the first place?

Comment: Only guys can answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are concatenation with `' vs '`. You should use same string with to split.

So use

```
string[] names = fullTeam.Split(new string[]{" vs "}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

My personal opinion is that You don't need to concatenate. Just access `countryA` and `countryB` separately

Comment: Hey @Rimpy :it says Wrong number of Indices inside[];expected1

Comment: @SiddharthKoya: Just a typo. It should be `new string[]{" vs "}`

Answer (score 2):

`fullTeam.Split(' ', '-')` -> `fullTeam.Split(new[]{" vs "}, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Comment: I feel like, to be safe, you might want to split on " vs " (spaces included). A quick check on Wikipedia's [List of Countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries) doesn't show any with "vs" in their name, but it still feels chancy to me. EDIT: Heck, if you're combining it in the query then splitting it later (which is weird to me; why not just return two distinct values?) then choose a special character (or sequence of characters) like | or ~ or / that is guaranteed not to appear in the returned names.

Comment: string[] names = fullTeam.Split(new string[](" vs "), StringSplitOptions.None);

Worked .. Thnkx Guys Much Appreciate it :)